# Как домен влияет на рекламу сайта?

Tags: com, реклама, веб-сайт

Какой домен лучше выбрать? Вопрос не в цене а в качестве. На какие параметры обращать внимание? заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо выбрать нормальный домен верхнего уровня. Т.е.:

- .com
- .org
- .net
- .ru
- и т.д.

Но *не* дешёвенький/бесплатный "левый" домен:

- .tk
- .gq
- и т.д.

И как бы нормальное название сайта тоже [не помешает](https://medium.com/better-marketing/the-11-worst-website-names-ever-fc59e2f3242a) ;D